# Postgres blocked AccessShareLock

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm having issues with what seem to be `select` statements being blocked in postgres.
I'm running this query to get currently executing queries:

```
SELECT a.datname,
         l.relation::regclass,
         l.transactionid,
         l.mode,
         l.GRANTED,
         a.usename,
         a.query,
         a.query_start,
         age(now(), a.query_start) AS "age",
         a.pid
FROM pg_stat_activity a
JOIN pg_locks l ON l.pid = a.pid
ORDER BY a.query_start asc;
```

And I see this: 
[image]

So some of the reads will be very very long-running (look at the age column), and all other operations for DB will be stopped.
As far as I understand from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/explicit-locking.html AccessShareLock can be blocked only by schema changes, which is not running on the DB atm.

When I run this:

```
SELECT blocked_locks.pid     AS blocked_pid,
         blocked_activity.usename  AS blocked_user,
         blocking_locks.pid     AS blocking_pid,
         blocking_activity.usename AS blocking_user,
         blocked_activity.query    AS blocked_statement,
         blocking_activity.query   AS current_statement_in_blocking_process
   FROM  pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocked_locks
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocked_activity  ON blocked_activity.pid = blocked_locks.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocking_locks 
        ON blocking_locks.locktype = blocked_locks.locktype
        AND blocking_locks.DATABASE IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.DATABASE
        AND blocking_locks.relation IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.relation
        AND blocking_locks.page IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.page
        AND blocking_locks.tuple IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.tuple
        AND blocking_locks.virtualxid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.virtualxid
        AND blocking_locks.transactionid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.transactionid
        AND blocking_locks.classid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.classid
        AND blocking_locks.objid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objid
        AND blocking_locks.objsubid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objsubid
        AND blocking_locks.pid != blocked_locks.pid

    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocking_activity ON blocking_activity.pid = blocking_locks.pid
   WHERE NOT blocked_locks.GRANTED;
```

nothing is being returned;

Does anyone have any explanation about what could cause this behaviour? Any tips to move forward?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Your image show that all rows have "granted" as 'true'.  Nothing is being blocked.

Comment: @jjanes ok, is there any idea why those queries can be hanging?

Comment: I mean where to start looking at it

Comment: pg_stat_activity view, although the utility of that has been massively improved since 9.1, so you might be out of luck there.  Also, I find the linux command `top` to be indispensable.  You want to hit "c" in it so it shows the long command names.

Comment: Yeah but this is managed aws rds service, no way to run top.